# Javascript - onClick event

Tags: javascript, canvas, onclick

So I currently have an image on a canvas and I want the page to reload once you click the image. The problem is that the page is reloading as soon as the "Go" function is called and not when the click event is initiated. Here is the bit of code.

```
function Go()
{
    myimage = new Image();
    myimage.src = "http://i.imgur.com/xcLDp.gif";

    ctx.drawImage(myimage, 294, 100);

    myimage.onClick = window.location.reload();
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something trivial, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Regards,

Matt

Edit: Added for Derek.

> Hey Derek I really appreciate the help. I'm going to be real
>   noob with you for a second as I'm pretty new to coding. So I'm trying
>   to implement the demo code you've shown me on my test website
>   [here](http://imstupid.net/matt/sq/test/jquery.html) but the error I
>   get back is "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".
>
> Now what I know is that "$" is a jQuery symbol, now I'm pretty new to
>   coding/javascript in general so just imagine how new I am to javascript
>   libraries (jQuery).
>
> I've downloaded jQuery and put it in the same directory then added
>   this line to the html:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> Am I doing something wrong? Why is it not picking up on the jquery
>   library?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: The image has not even been appended to anywhere in the DOM, how can you click it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "reloading" is actually an *illusion*. When you do

```
myimage.onClick = window.location.reload();
```

That `reload()` is excuted right away.

What you really intended to do is:

```
myimage.onClick = window.location.reload;
```

But why it is an illusion? Because you can't even click the image, since it is *nowhere* in DOM. The image is in your `<canvas>`, therefore it should be:

```
document.querySelector("canvas").addEventListener("click",function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Also you will have to calculate if the pointer is above the image. See demo.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/QuAVc/

Comment: yeah, it's not immediately obvious (going by the other answers) that that you can't attach a listener to a bunch of pixels, which is what the image winds up being when all is said and done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

This works although it means that anywhere you click on the canvas will cause a refresh, is there a way to specifically target the image on the canvas?

Comment: Yes, you can test if the cursor's coordinate is inside the area of the image.

Comment: @Derek 

I've edited my original post with a reply directed to you regarding the demo you've just shown me. I didn't have enough space to fit it all in a comment.

Comment: @Matt - You have to flip the order of your 2 scripts, which means `jquery-1.7.2.js` will have to come first. (Always put your scripts after loading the libraries)

Answer (score 3):

That is because you called `reload` immediately by `()`.

```
myimage.onClick = window.location.reload;
```

***Edit:***
And you can't get a click event fired on the image, you should bind to a existing dom element like:

```
myimage.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector("canvas").addEventListener("click", window.location.reload);
};
```

Comment: you're correct about how to append a listener to something, but notice that this listener can't get invoked in the current code since the image is never being added to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you are miss something, you must pass window.location.reload as a callback(do not put parenthess), try this:

```
function Go() {
  myimage = new Image();
  myimage.src = "http://joinmissinglink.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/go-button5.jpg";

  ctx.drawImage(myimage, 294, 100);

  myimage.onClick = window.location.reload; //window.location.reload is a callback
}
```